# I am able to access /dev/ttyS0 device file in two different processes at same time. Why?

Tags: c, linux, device

I read some where that, any device file can be accessed by only one process at a time. But in my case I am able to access my `/dev/ttyS0` device file by two different processes at the same time. In my case I opened a `minicom` with the `/dev/ttyS0` and then I wrote a program in c, which opens the same file and tries to read/write from it. I am able to open both at the same time. Why is it happening in my case?

Comment: Why not?  Lots of processes have a given terminal as the I/O device at any one time, in general.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Are you saying terminal device files are different from other device files?

Comment: No; they're the same as device files, and multiple processes can have most device files open at any given time.  Unix/Linux does not enforce exclusive access on devices.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Can you elaborate your comment as an answer?

Comment: In the `/dev/ttyS0` case, only one process would receive the bytes, wouldn't it? Hence the `/var/lock/LCK..ttyS0` mechanism for locking serial ports.

On the other hand, it seems that multiple processes can open `/dev/input/eventX`, and all receive the same input events.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comments converted to an answer:

- Why not? Lots of processes have a given terminal as the I/O device at any one time, in general.

> Are you saying terminal device files are different from other device files?

No; they're the same as device files, and multiple processes can have most device files open at any given time. Unix/Linux does not enforce exclusive access on devices.  Device files such as `/dev/null` can be in use by many processes at one time.  Disk devices can be opened by multiple processes (though generally, you only want one process at a time using any given device, but some DBMS will have multiple processes accessing a single disk device).  When a process forks, both processes have access to the same set of files.